# When downloading a zip file with requests the file ends up being corrupted

Tags: python-3.x, download, python-requests, zip, corrupt

Why does a downloaded zip file using requests end up corrupted? Trying to make a program that starts a download a specified time.

```
import requests
import time
import datetime

tim = datetime.datetime.now()
print("########So Far Only Works With mp4, png, jpg, pkg and exe files########")
time.sleep(1)
DLTime = input("Time\nHH:MM\n")
url = input("URL:\n")
Location = ("/Users/'user'/Downloads/" + input("File Name\n"))
print("Waiting...")

while(True):
   tim = datetime.datetime.now()
   if tim.strftime("%H:%M") == DLTime:
       print("Download Started")
       myfile = requests.get(url)
       open(Location, 'wb').write(myfile.content)
       print("\nDownload Finished")
       input("Press Enter To Finish")
       exit()
   time.sleep(1)
```

Note: Had to use tim not time due to interference with other parts of code.

Note: User replaced with 'user'.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your file download does not use [streams](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow) which defers downloading the response body until you access it. You can try this snippet for downloading. It additionally adds a progress bar

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import requests

#... other stuff

url = "http://example.com/myfile.zip"
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

with open(„myfile“, "wb") as handle:
    for data in tqdm(response.iter_content()):
        handle.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm not sure what could be your specific problem but, I saw a lot of other problems with your code so I rewrote it:

```py
import datetime
import time
import requests

time_begginning = datetime.datetime.now()
print("########So Far Only Works With mp4, png, jpg, pkg and exe files########")
time_provided_raw = input('Enter the time you want to download the file (format HH:MM): ')
time_provided = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_provided_raw, "%H:%M")
url_to_retreive = input('Enter the url from where to download the file: ')
file_name_to_save = input('Enter the file name you want to save this file: ')
destination = f"/Users/'user'/Downloads/{file_name_to_save}"

scheduled_time = time_begginning.replace(hour=time_provided.hour, 
                                         minute=time_provided.minute, 
                                         second=0, microsecond=0)
if scheduled_time < time_begginning:
    scheduled_time += datetime.timedelta(days=1)

timestamp_now = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
timestamp_schedule = scheduled_time.timestamp()
delay_to_wait = timestamp_schedule - timestamp_now
print('Waiting…')
time.sleep(delay_to_wait)

print("Download Started")
file_retreived = requests.get(url_to_retreive)
print("Download finished")
with open(destination, 'wb') as destination_file:
    print(f'Saving to {destination}')
    destination_file.write(file_retreived.content)
```

Instead of going through a loop for checking if it's the right time each second with will keep you CPU busy, I:

1. Collecting all the information needed
2. Compute how long we would have to wait before downloading

   - If the time entered is in the past, I presume that it means that we have to wait until tomorrow
3. Sleep once for that time period (instead of waking up every second)
4. Download the file
5. Save that file with the name provided

I've tried it with a few different zip files on the web and it seems to work.